# How to create read-only directory in Java on Windows

Tags: java, windows, permissions, directory

I want to create a read-only directory from Java on Windows, so that I can't create any directory inside. I have this code which should fail on `Files.createDirectory(directory);`

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    var foo = Paths.get("foo");
    var directory = Paths.get("foo/bar");
    Files.createDirectory(foo);
    var view = Files.getFileAttributeView(foo, AclFileAttributeView.class);
    var entries = new ArrayList<AclEntry>();
    for (var acl : view.getAcl()) {
        var perms = new LinkedHashSet<>(acl.permissions());
        perms.remove(AclEntryPermission.WRITE_DATA);
        perms.remove(AclEntryPermission.APPEND_DATA);
        perms.remove(AclEntryPermission.ADD_SUBDIRECTORY);
        var ae = AclEntry.newBuilder()
                         .setType(acl.type())
                         .setPrincipal(acl.principal())
                         .setPermissions(perms)
                         .setFlags(acl.flags())
                         .build();
        entries.add(ae);
    }
    view.setAcl(entries);
    Files.createDirectory(directory);
}
```

However, it's passing without an issue. When I create file inside, it fails as expected. But I can still create a directory. How can I create real read-only directory?

Comment: your code is actually working as expected for my enterprise Windows 7 x64. The parent folder is been created and the code is throwing an exception on the last line indicating that I don't have permission to do so.

Comment: It appears that [`setAcl`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/attribute/AclFileAttributeView.html#setAcl(java.util.List)) doesn't allow setting security-descriptor control flags, such as [`SE_DACL_PROTECTED`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379566). Without that, you can't block entries inherited from the parent directory. Use icacls.exe to check for inherited entries that allow creating subdirectories (i.e. append data or generic write, or simple write, modify, or full control).

Comment: I looked further into this in versions 9 and 10 of the JDK. It turns out the lack of inheritance control isn't a problem because it uses the obsolete function [`SetFileSecurity`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379577), which doesn't automatically propagate inheritance. Implicitly in this case the security descriptor is set with the `SE_DACL_PROTECTED` flag, and no entries are marked as inherited.